# Can I buy Ether directly to Ledger Nano S?

Tags: mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Is it possible to buy Ether directly to Ledger Nano S? Because I don't want to download Mist, then create account there, and then wait for the entire blockchain to sync, mainly because while syncing, Malwarebytes is going crazy blocking many outbound IPs! I hope that they're not there to steal my Ether! That's why I want to directly buy Ether to the Ledger, or that would not be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, got to go through the process like everyone else. You wouldn't want to accidentally get your ether stolen/siphoned off if you gave it a direct line to what should be a secure wallet.

Try this tutorial listed on their support page, its as direct as it can get while being secure.

https://ledger.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005199489-How-to-buy-Ethereum